# Add outlet to circuit with dishwasher and disposal

Tags: electrical

I currently have one 20A circuit feeding my dishwasher and garbage disposal. The garbage disposal is also switched. There's a 12AWG wire hard wired into the back of the dishwasher, and the source also goes to a switch by the sink. Then there's a 12/2 wire that goes from the switch to an outlet under the sink for the disposal.

I have a automatic faucet that requires power. I've been using batteries for a while, and I just recently got an AC adapter so that I don't have to change batteries so often. Now I just need to find a way to wire it.

My plan was to take the wire that's going into the dishwasher and feed it into the area under the sink (the dishwasher is immediately adjacent to the sink), then add a small junction box and receptacle and send the wire back to the dishwasher. All I plan to plug into this receptacle is that AC adapter which provides 1Amp at 12 volts DC, so a miniscule amount.

My questions are:

1. Can I do this?
2. Is it safe?
3. Is it up to code?
4. If not, is there a better option?

Edit to add more info requested in comments:

- I'm in Utah.
- The dishwasher's tag lists: `Total Amps: 9.6`.
- The disposal is 1/3 HP. The label says 5.6 Amps.

Comment: What state are you in (so we can look up the code version) it sounds like the faucet is only a few watts.

Comment: How many watts/amps is the dishwasher, and how many HP is the disposal for that matter?

Comment: While you may only plan to plug the small DC adapter into this particular outlet, you must design it for anyone to plug anything into it at some point in the future, thus the questions above.

Comment: @EdBeal: I'm in Utah

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I updated the post with the amps.

Comment: Can you get a DC adapter that puts out the correct voltage and has a hole for a mounting screw on it...?

Comment: The code allows DW connection by plug and receptacle only in cabinet next to DW. After routing the cable that feeds the DW to the sink cabinet put a duplex there and get a cord for the DW.  Both halves of duplex will be used avoiding having an open receptacle for "equipment not fastened in place".

Answer (score 1):

### I'd use a screw-mount 12VDC adapter for this

Given your situation, and the fact that NEC 210.23(A)(2) limits the *total* amps of fastened-in-place equipment to 50% of the circuit ampacity if light fixtures or non-fastened-in-place equipment is also present on the circuit:

> **(2) Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place.** The total rating
> of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires, shall not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere
> rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization
> equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.

, I'd replace the 12/2 from the switch down to the existing disposal receptacle with a 12/3 and wire the disposal receptacle as *half-switched* with the switched receptacle on *top*.  This lets you then use a screw-mounted 12VDC "wall-wart" of the type used in security alarm work to power the faucet; the mounting screw for said wall-wart replaces the screw holding the faceplate to the receptacle yoke, by the way.